# Casting to Chromecast without Google Play Service

Tags: google-play-services, chromecast

I am a long time CyanogenMod user without any Google Play Services installed. 
It seems like Android Chromecast apps all require Google Play Services. There are some tools (UnifiedNlp, NOGAPPS) replacing parts of Google API, but it does not seem like they are providing necessary API for casting to Chromecast.

Is there any chance to cast to a Chromecast (2015) without installing Google software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some initial work has been done in the [microG project](https://github.com/microg) from Ma-rv-in, but nothing usable so far.

I personally use MultiRom and boot on a ROM which has Play Services installed to use my Chromecast.